# Understanding DFT and IDFT

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, dft

I am moving my first steps in the Discrete Fourier Transform and trying to practise it in WolframCloud.

One of my first experiments was to input the Heavside function: Sampling the function on 8 points {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0} I have got {1.06066,-0.853553,0.353553,0.146447,-0.353553,0.146447,0.353553,-0.853553} whose plot resembles the sinc function up to some factor.

1. Doubling the number of samples {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0} the program returned {1.5 +0.I,-1.16116-0.23097I,0.426777 +0.176777I,0.143182 +0.0956709I,-0.25-0.25I,0.0639252 +0.0956709I,0.0732233 +0.176777I,-0.0459428-0.23097I,0. +0.I,-0.0459428+0.23097I,0.0732233 -0.176777I,0.0639252 -0.0956709I,-0.25+0.25I,0.143182 -0.0956709I,0.426777 -0.176777I,-1.16116+0.23097I} which contains the not expected imaginary part.
2. In the helpless attempt to understand it better I sampled the sinc function {-3.89817×10^-17,-0.206748,0.413497,1.,0.413497,-0.206748,-3.89817×10-^17,0.103374} and the command InverseFourier on the former array produced {0.536295+0.I,-0.37035-0.37035I,0.+0.536295I,0.0779633-0.0779633I,0.0484778+0.I,0.0779633+0.0779633I,0.-0.536295I,-0.37035+0.37035I} which has nothing to do with the Heviside function.

Can anybody help me to understand something more?

Thank you very much
Danilo